# How do we add properties to JS spread operator?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Below I have added patientId and inusranceId to spread operator , just wanted to see if there is better approach to achieve this task ?

main.js

```
const Response = await getData(re);
const patientId = "AW364747";
const insuranceId = "0000786622";


logger().info('Response=', { ...Response, drugName: '[REDACTED]' , patientId, insuranceId});
```

Comment: What's not good about this solution?

Comment: @NineBerry i want patientId and inusranceId part of the Response.

Comment: if you want to add properties to `Response`, you can do it like `Response.patientId = ...`. Another way is using [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), example: `Object.assign(Response, {dugName: '[REDACTED]', ...})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is correct.

```
let newResponse = {...Response, drugName: '[REDACTED]'}
```

Will either add drugName property if it is missing from Response. OR it will override the drugName property if it is in Response.

```
let newResponse = { drugName: 'defaultname', ...Response}
```

will do the opposite, if Response contains drugName it will override drugName: 'defualtname' or if it doesn't exist in Response it will add drugName.

Examples:

```
const Response = { prop: 'some prop', drugName: 'Original Drug'}

const spreadFirst = { ...Response, drugName: 'New drug'}
// spreadFirst = { prop: 'some prop', drugName: 'New drug'}

const spreadLast = { drugName: 'Newest Drug', ...Response}
// spreadLast = { prop: 'some prop', drugName: 'Original Drug'}
```

Comment: I dont see any difference in both of your above approaches output would be same right

Comment: my questions was if we add any property where it would be added , would it add new properties at same level as others like drugName in the Response object

Comment: @hussain so first if spread comes first whatever follows will replace properties in Response. If spread comes last then Response will replace whatever is before it. drugName will be at the same level as all the properties within Response. Just as if you simply Response.drugname = "drugname"

Answer (score 0):

There is more clear and direct approach

```js
let Response = { name: 'John' }; // await getData(re);

Response.drugName    = '[REDACTED]'; 
Response.patientId   = 'AW364747';
Response.insuranceId = '0000786622';

console.log(Response)
```

Comment: The question specifically asks to use spread operator. This also mutates Response which may not be desirable.

Comment: There something like "spread operator" doesnt exists - there is [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and we cannot add anything to it. OP not mention that mutations are not acceptable

Comment: The spread syntax uses the (...) operator Either way its semantics and the question clearly called for the spread syntax/operator .